# How to insert external javascript files in meteor js (0.9.2.2) template

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am using following code to insert javascript files in template :

```
 _.each([
    "/assets/global/plugins/jquery-1.11.0.min.js",

    "/assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js",

    "/assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js",
    "/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js",
    "/assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
    "/assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js",
    "/assets/global/plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js",
    "/assets/global/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js",
    "/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"


], function(script, ready) { jQuery.getScript(script, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr){

    console.log( data ); // Data returned
    console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    console.log( "Load was performed." );

    })
});
```

I am getting following results (only one sample out of 10), all 10 files showing success messages :

```
(function(){var t=[].slice;!fu"[…] admin.js:63
"success" admin.js:64
200 admin.js:65

"Load was performed."
```

But when I see "View Generated Source" in Firefox developer tool, I can't see any inserted JavaScript files in html code. Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me. jQuery.getScript() does not seem to change anything in the DOM, it simply runs the code virtually. Try adding a file that has `console.log('test');` as its contents.

By the way, in your posted code, you are loading jQuery using jQuery's own function. For this jQuery must already be loaded. It seems that you need to rethink how you are loading your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you using ajax calls?

Did you know, Meteor merges head Tags of all html files. So you can make as example a 'scripts.html' File with content:

```
<head>
<script src=...
</head>
```